# Expecation of Linear Regression Coefficients

Tags: regression, probability, expected-value, regression-coefficients, conditional-expectation

Let the entity ${\widehat{\boldsymbol\beta}}$ be a linear estimator (not necessarily the least squares estimator) of the true coefficient ${{\boldsymbol\beta}}$ in the regression of  on . In this context, I have read that:

$${\Bbb E}{\Big\{}{\Bbb E}{\big[}{\big(}{\Bbb E}({\widehat{\boldsymbol\beta}\mid\mathbf {X}}) - {\Bbb E}({\widehat{\boldsymbol\beta}}){\big)} {\big(}{\widehat{\boldsymbol\beta}} - {\Bbb E}({\widehat{\boldsymbol\beta}}){\big)}^{\mathbf T} \bigl\lvert {\mathbf X}{\big]}{\Big\}}$$

$$= {\Bbb E}{\Big\{}{\big(}{\underline{{\Bbb E}({\widehat{\boldsymbol\beta}\mid\mathbf {X}}) - {\Bbb E}({\widehat{\boldsymbol\beta}})}}{\big)} {\Bbb E}{\big[}{\big(}{\widehat{\boldsymbol\beta}} - {\Bbb E}({\widehat{\boldsymbol\beta}}){\big)}^{\mathbf T} \bigl\lvert {\mathbf X}{\big]}{\Big\}}$$

Q.) I am perplexed as to how the first term (*underlined*) extricated itself out of expectation unscathed. As far as I can get it, ${\Bbb E}({\widehat{\boldsymbol\beta}\mid\mathbf {X}})$ s a function of , so its fair enough to release it from the operation. But what about ${\Bbb E}({\widehat{\boldsymbol\beta}})$,  seeing that it depends not only on , but also on ? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although $\hat\beta$ is a function of both $X$ and $y$, $\mathbb E[\hat\beta]$ is a constant because expectation is taken over all RVs inside. Let's call it $c$, and take the inside of the outermost expected value only. The expression becomes the following:

$$\begin{align}\mathbb E[\overbrace{(\mathbb E[\hat\beta|X]-c)}^{\text{given X this is const, call it A}}(\hat\beta-c)^T|X]&=A\ \mathbb E[\hat\beta-c|X]^T\end{align}$$

when substituted back, you get the expression in the question.